# How to use `execute immediate` to assign a value to a variable?

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, execute-immediate

I am trying to use `execute immediate` as a special requirement for assigning the value of a variable. I am using the following code and getting the exception as below.

```
declare
  lv_kyc_main_GBL KYC_GBL_MAIN.KYC_MAIN%rowtype;
  l_str varchar2(400);

  a number(10);
begin
  select *
    into lv_kyc_main_GBL
    from KYC_GBL_MAIN.KYC_MAIN
   where rownum = 1;

  -- l_str:='lv_kyc_main_GBL.legal_name'||':='||'''TEST''';

  l_str := 'lv_kyc_main_GBL.legal_name := ''TEST''';
  dbms_output.put_line(l_str);

  execute immediate (l_str);
end;
/
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
anonymous block completed
lv_kyc_main_GBL.legal_name := 'TEST'
```

Error starting at line 4 in command:

```
declare
  lv_kyc_main_GBL KYC_GBL_MAIN.KYC_MAIN%rowtype;
  l_str varchar2(400);

  a number(10);
begin
  select *
    into lv_kyc_main_GBL
    from KYC_GBL_MAIN.KYC_MAIN
   where rownum = 1;

  --l_str:='lv_kyc_main_GBL.legal_name'||':='||'''TEST''';

  l_str := 'lv_kyc_main_GBL.legal_name := ''TEST''';
  dbms_output.put_line(l_str);

  execute immediate (l_str);
end;
/

Error report:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 14
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"
*Cause:    
*Action:
lv_kyc_main_GBL.legal_name := 'TEST'
```

I can't understand what is wrong in the following assignment. It just works fine if I do the assignment separately as:

```
lv_kyc_main_GBL.legal_name := 'TEST'
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the `;` on your assignment? `l_str := 'lv_kyc_main_GBL.legal_name := ''TEST'';';`

Comment: @JorgeCampos : I tried that just now still the same error is coming .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but to run a PLSQL block (ie not an SQL statement) in execute immediate, you need to wrap it in begin ... end;

Also, you cannot assign to a variable outside the execute immediate block from within it, so in your example, attempting to assign directly to lv_kyc_main_GBL.legal_name will not work. You need to use bind variables for this.  I think something like the following will work (I don't have Oracle running here right now):

```
declare
  lv_kyc_main_GBL KYC_GBL_MAIN.KYC_MAIN%rowtype;
  l_str varchar2(400);

  a number(10);
begin
 select * into lv_kyc_main_GBL
 from KYC_GBL_MAIN.KYC_MAIN where rownum=1;

 l_str := 'begin :b1 := ''TEST''; end';
 dbms_output.put_line(l_str);

 execute immediate (l_str) using out lv_kyc_main_GBL.legal_name;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This works. If I am using two bind variables b1 and b2 there how should the execute immediate statement look like ?

Comment: Just separate the parameters with comma `using out lv_kyc_main_GBL.legal_name, anotherVar;`

Comment: @JorgeCampos: The main objective behind using an assignment like that is I am having a varchar field_name whose value denote the field name of lv_kyc_main_GBL row variable and another varchar field_value which denote the value of lv_kyc_main_GBL.field_name. I need to run something like  lv_kyc_main_GBL.field_name=field_value . Where field_name and field_value are both variables. How to solve such a case ?

Comment: `l_str := 'begin :b1 := :b2; end';` and pass both variables as mentioned im my earlier comment.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Just saw this comment now, this should work. Thanks a lot